# Outbound routing on Azure VM

Tags: firewall, azure, virtual-machines

I have a test VM in Azure, private IP 10.0.0.4 running an IIS site.

I have a Watchguard firewall VM in Azure with two interfaces, one has a public IP and a private IP of 10.0.1.2.

The other interface on the firewall has a private IP 10.0.0.5 (same range as VM).

I have created a SNAT rule in the firewall, so that any external traffic coming in on port 80 goes across to 10.0.0.4.

I can see the traffic coming into the firewall and hitting my rule, but it never presents the IIS site and just times out.

Any ideas? I can ping the firewall from the VM and visa versa.

(the test vm does have its own public IP and I can see the IIS site directly via this OK).

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to redirect external traffic to a "virtual host" (test VM) you should create a DNAT rule in your Firewall VM, that's the way it works by definition.

Note: I'm assuming that by SNAT you're referring to source NAT since there's some terminology confusion, otherwise omit my response.